# Apache Ignite 2.11.0 startup error "No matching constructor class org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server" with ignited-rest-http

Tags: ignite

The [Ignite Official guide](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/2.11.0/restapi) to enable the rest HTTP module was working in version 2.10.0. However, when I tried to install 2.11.0 on another machine independently and followed this guide to enable the ignite-rest-http model. It throws the above error when startup.

Things that I have done

1. moved ignite-rest-http to libs/
2. configured the jetty.xml as instruction by the guide
3. added the connectorConfiguration property in the default-config.xml

remarks: I am using linuxOS and openJDK 8.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you're changing the parameters, there's no need to create a jetty.xml. Just moving `ignite-rest-http` from optional to libs is sufficient.

Having said that, if you need to change parameters it should work. It appears that there's a typo in the example `jetty.xml` file. The first lines should be:

```
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
    <Arg name="threadpool">
        <!-- Default queued blocking thread pool -->
```

It's subtle... in the documentation it says `threadPool`.